# Unable to authenticate kubernetes cluster with the certificate-authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I have a kubeadm cluster. I modified the `.kube/config` file by exporting out hardcoded `certificate-authority-data` value (the base64 of ca certificate) to another file called `ca.b64.crt`. I modified also the `client-certificate` and `client-key` by having their values in another files in the disk.

So the result `.kube/config` file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.b64.crt
    server: https://172.31.127.100:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/pki/admins/admin.b64.crt
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/pki/admins/admin.b64.key
```

The problem is that whenever I try to use kubectl (e.g to get pods), I got:

```
xxxx:~$ k get po
error: unable to load root certificates: unable to parse bytes as PEM block
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just reload the cluster, it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the issue. `certificate-authority-data` uses base64 string of the crt or key while `certificate-authority` uses the crt or key files (without being base64)

Comment: I ended up just manually modifying the file and directly adding the `certificate-authority-data` entry as that was a lot easier

Answer (score 2):

**Below troubleshooting steps will help you resolve issues related to the format or content of the certificate files**

1.Check to see if the certificate files are at the expected locations.

2.Check that the certificate and key files are in the correct format, particularly PEM.

3.Check that the certificate and key files are read-only for the user using the 'kubectl' command.

4.Try with enhanced privileges like ‘sudo kubectl'.

Refer to the [doc](https://kodekloud.com/blog/certified-kubernetes-administrator-exam-security/#:%7E:text=kubectl%20get%20serviceaccount-,Introduction%20to%20TLS,-Transport%20Layer%20Security) Introduction to TLS written by Mumshad Mannambeth for more information.

The error  “Unable to load  root certificate” seems like if we paste the cert from a browser.It is most likely that we may miss the  CR and LF characters by not reading/loading the cert file.

you can use something like https://www.base64encode.org/. Simply insert the PEM data and encode!

Comment: running kubectl with enhanced privileges helped in my case. thanks